# (C++) Why is the code written in the description/body of this question giving 10(all) 0's as the output?

Tags: c++, output

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> g1;
  
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
     g1.push_back(i * 10);
     cout << g1[i] << " ";
    }
    
}
```

The above written code is giving me output as "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0" that 10 0's with a space after each 0 of them, as written in the code. But in the code, it is written to add at the end of the vector the iterator*10:

`g1.push_back(i * 10);`

and the output code

`cout << g1[i] << " ";`

is giving 0 for every iterations(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) when it should be giving:

10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100

as the output

Output:

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Expected output:

10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100

Comment: Your index `i` starts at 1, but *actual* indices start at 0. You need to adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: `i` is inthe range [1, 10] so `cout << g1[i] << " "` always prints one after the end of the `vector`.  Undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, @cigien I think I got it. I will post the answer with an explanation and mention your comments.

Comment: Thanks, @G.M. I think I got it. I will post the answer with an explanation and mention your comments.

Comment: C++ and C use 0-based *cardinal offset*.  Pascal and Lua use a 1-based *ordinal index*.  Which is better...?   Meh, they both have pros & cons.

Answer (score 2):

```
 cout << g1[i] << " ";
```

should be

```
 cout << g1[i - 1] << " ";
```

In C++ arrays and vectors use zero based indexing.

Answer (score 0):

As cigien and G.M. explained in the comments to the question above, over here in the code, the iteration should start at 0 since in the vector the indices start at 0 or else the `g1.push_back(i * 10);` part of the code can give anything because that's undefined behavior as pointed out by πάντα-ῥεῖ in the comments of this answer.

So either `for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)` needs to be modified to be `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)` or as noted by ceorron in their answer we can have `cout << g1[i] << " ";` modified to be `cout << g1[i - 1] << " ";` to make
the code give expected output after compilation and execution.

Comment: _"part of the code will always give 0 because the element right after the end of the vector is 0."_ that's not true,  anything can happen because that's _undefined behavior_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks, I have modified my answer to reflect what you have pointed out.